# Write query SQLite with selectionArgs

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I use the `String` `selectionArgs` in `query()` statement. I want write a `query` with 5 parameters. If one of parameters is null I do not want to use it. How do I do ?

for example:

```
Cursor cur = sqlite_obj.query(TableName, null, "UID = ? AND Age > ? AND Room = ? AND Adre = ?", new String[] { "31", "" ,"3", ""}, null, null, null, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you insist on using `selectionArgs` you can do it like below:

first check your arguments and then build your query according to it for example:

```
    String[] myArray = new String[] { "31", "" ,"3", ""};

    List<String> myQueryValue = new ArrayList<String>();

    String myQueryParam = "";

    if(!myArray[0].equal("")){

       myQueryParam =  myQueryParam + "UID = ? AND ";
       myQueryValue.add(myArray[0]);
    }

    if(!myArray[1].equal("")){

         myQueryParam =  myQueryParam + "Age > ? AND "; 
         myQueryValue.add(myArray[1]);
    }

   if(!myArray[2].equal("")){

         myQueryParam =  myQueryParam + "Room = ? AND ";
         myQueryValue.add(myArray[2]);
    }

    if(!myArray[3].equal("")){

         myQueryParam =  myQueryParam + "AND Adre = ?";
         myQueryValue.add(myArray[3]);
    }
```

and at the end

```
String[] finalValue = new String[ myQueryValue.size() ];
myQueryValue.toArray( finalValue );
Cursor cur = sqlite_obj.query(TableName, null, myQueryParam, finalValue , null, null, null, null);
```

you can also use `loop` to create your values and query param.